# Environment variable change made in a batch is not reflecting immediately

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am trying to set the following environment variable , and invoking a .exe file . This particular takes the value of the variable and creates metadata files.

But the value set while running the batch is only reflect if i run it the second time . Is there a way to reflect the environment variable change immediately?

Following is the sample

```
setx -m USER_HOME "D:\\user_home"

start "" C:\\sample.exe
```

Comment: In this case, you probably only need `set`, not `setx`.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting explorer.exe might be enough. Try `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` and start it again using `explorer.exe` after setting your variable.

Comment: No, that won't affect the running instance of cmd.exe.